# 301 Redirects Between Two Domains on Same Hosting Plan

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, shared-hosting

Recently purchased domain made the Primary Domain in my shared hosting plan.

Using the redirect option in Cpanel, olddomain.com home page is properly redirecting to newdomain.com home page as it should.

No files were removed or moved at all. Newdomain.com uses all the same Wordpress files that olddomain.com did, and everything **(including Htaccess, if that helps)** is in /public_html.

Olddomain.com is now currently sitting as an ADDOn domain in Cpanel on same hosting plan.

Now how do I set up "one for one" 301 redirects for individual URLs? So *olddomain.com/contact-us* should redirect to *newdomain.com/contact-us* for example.

With olddomain.com being an AddOn domain, would it be as easy as adding ReWrite rules to the HTACCESS?

Truly appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with `.htacess` as suggested by Anthony. I just make it little simpler for you.

**Solution 1:**

You can use this code to redirect the `Old Domain` Name to the `New Domain Name`. (Only domain redirect)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

**Solution 2:**
If you want to redirect particular Pages as well use the code below. (Don't forget to add `RewriteEngine on` at the beginning)

```
# 301 Redirect from OLD to NEW Page
Redirect 301 /old-page https://www.new-domain.com/new-page
```

You can add multiple redirects to redirect each page like

```
Redirect 301 /contact-us https://www.new-domain.com/contact-us
Redirect 301 /about https://www.new-domain.com/about
Redirect 301 /blog https://www.new-domain.com/blog
```

and so on.... 
Redirect for the root domain to old-domain.com to new-domain.com can be done using

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.new-domain.com/
```

**Solution 3:**

You can also add the following code to redirect the domain as well as the pages to the new domain using the following `.htacess` code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old-domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.new-domain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

**Solution 4:**
You can also do the same using cPanel.

1. Log in to `cPanel` and go to the `Redirects` Option under `Domains`
   Check this image for better understanding.
   [cPanel Redirects Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrmHR.jpg)
2. Add the redirect. [Check the Image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhoxL.jpg).
3. Choose the Redirect type. (`301` or `302`)
4. Select the domain from the drop-down. (Addon domain will show up too).
5. do not add anything inside the `/`.
6. type your new domain name inside `Redirects to`
7. Select `www. redirection:` option as per your requirement.
8. Check the Wild Card Redirect box

You are done. cPanel will write the .htaccess code for you.

> Remember the **solution 3** and **Solution 4** will only work if the
>   old domain's `filename` and new domains `file names` are same. For
>   example `old-domain.com/something` will be redirected to
>   `new-domain.com/something` but it can not be redirected to the
>   `new-domain.com/otherthing`.
>
> If you have different file name for the new & old domain then use
>   **Solution 2** or don't check on the `www. redirection:` option for **Solution 4** and add the page name/file name on the `/` box (Option number 5).
>
> You can delete all the contents from the `addon-domain.com folder`
>   using cPanel File Manager or FTP Clients, except the `.htacess` file
>   to save space. Just keep the `.htaccess` file. That's enough for you.
>   But always keep a backup copy in case anything goes wrong.

Hopefully, this is helpful for you.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, the solution that I posted is working as it should, but I've accepted your answer as the official solution because you didn't downvote my question like someone else did and took the time to offer multiple ways that I could go about achieving what I was asking for. Truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

All it took was adding a separate .htaccess file in the olddomain ADDON directory containing one-for-one 301 redirects as well as a ReWrite rule for the index.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,QSA,L]

Redirect 301 "/blog-post/" "https://www.newdomain.com/blog-post"
```